# Parsing session data to my INSERT Function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to parse my member_data session into my function, however am unsure with how to do this. My function is

```
function createTransaction(){
    // Insert into the transactions table
    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (mem_id, OrderDate, Ship_Phone, Ship_Address, Ship_City, Ship_County, Ship_PostCode, Ship_Country) VALUES()");
    if($query1) {
        // Get the highest ID in the transactions table. This should be the ID of the row we just inserted.
        $tempInfo = mysql_query("SELECT `order_id` FROM `transactions` ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $tempInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($tempInfo);
        $orderId = $tempInfo['order_id'];

        // Insert into the transaction details table.
        $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactionDetails` (Order_ID, Product_ID, Price, Quantity) VALUES({$orderId}, {$item_id}, {$price}, {$each_item})");

        if($query2) {
            // Success.
        } else {
            // Error occurred.
            echo 'Query2 Error: ' . mysql_error();
        }
    } else {
        // Error occurred.
        echo 'Query1 Error: ' . mysql_error();
    }
}
```

And where the Values is (Line 3), I want to insert the data from my session

```
$session_mem_id = $_SESSION['mem_id'];
$member_data  = member_data($session_mem_id, 'mem_id', 'mem_email', 'mem_password', 'mem_address', 'mem_city', 'mem_postcode', 'mem_county', 'mem_country', 'mem_first_name', 'mem_last_name', 'password_recover', 'allow_email', 'admin', 'mem_tel');
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `({$_SESSION['mem_id']}, {$_SESSION['mem_email']}, {$_SESSION['mem_password']}, ...)`

Comment: Give me a mysql error

Comment: Forgot the `'` around the values, e.g., `'{$_SESSION['mem_id']}'`. You know SQL, right?

Comment: What exactly do you want to insert? Your table seems to have a column named `mem_id` but the last line of your code suggests something completely else.

Comment: @JaredFarrish it works now, but data only adds to mem_id, order_id and orderdate, everything else is blank

Comment: That's your code. Troubleshoot it. You get the idea about *how* to include it in a query, at least.